# Illegal Characters in path using FileStream

Tags: c#

I am using a FileSteam and passing a path into it. However when I attempt to pass the file stream into a new XSSFWorkbook, I get an error stating there is illegal characters in the path.

The path that is being passed into the FileSteam is:

```
C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Source\\Repos\\Stack Emissions API\\Uploads\\Instrument Data Files\\RP000001073_EMT00098_CGS_0_Horiba350.xlsx
```

I'm not sure where the illegal characters are here? Maybe i'm missing something obvious. In the following snippet, "Save" contains the path mentioned above, and the crash happens at the workbook section when the file_strm is passed in.

```
Stream file_Strm = new FileStream(Save, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

string file_Name = getFileName(Save);

if (file_Name.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
{
    XSSFFormulaEvaluator formula;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;

    using (file_Strm)
    {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file_Strm); // XSSFWorkbook for XLSX
        formula = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(workbook);
    }
}
```

Comment: So `Save` is a `string`?

Comment: Save is from "foreach (string Save in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uploadPath))" which returns a string

Comment: And `Stream file_Strm` is the line that's throwing the exception?

Comment: No it's this part:
"   workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file_Strm); // XSSFWorkbook for XLSX"

Comment: That's weird. The issue doesn't appear to be with the file path you supplied - that would throw an exception on the `new FileStream(` line. I'm not sure waht the issue is, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is the file you are opening in a correct xlsx format? It could be because you are giving some unexpected file to `XSSFWorkbook`

Comment: copy that file to another simple folder, i.e. c:\tmp, read from there. same error?

Comment: @JorgeMachado You are totally right actually, those files are now corrupted, it would appear that when these files are being renamed by the client app, it is corrupting them. This gives me something else to look at, thank you :)

Comment: Double backslashes are not allowed in paths, so check if you actually use double backslashes in the path.

Comment: `formula` takes `workbook` on creation. `workbook` takes `file_Strm` on creation. `file_Strm` is protected by a `using` statement. So what happens when `file_Strm` is disposed? Maybe comment out the `using` and see if that changes things.

Comment: By instantiating your stream outside of the using block, you may have streams that never get disposed because the filename doesn't start with .xlsx (so your using statement never runs.  Consider moving your stream creation to the using block.